# Can not find Points in Polygons and Spatial Query in QGIS 2.18.9

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am using some old tutorial with Points in Polygon and Spatial Query but can not find these options in QGIS. Do I need to turn on some options to see them?

Answer (score 3):

It is in menu `Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Count points in polygon`. If you don't see it maybe your `Processing` plugin is deactivated.

You can run `Count points in polygon` also from processing toolbox, just start typing "count points" in filter to see results:

[image]

*edit:*

I forgot the spatial query part, so one option is (as @ahmadhanb suggest)  `Spatial Query` plugin which gives you the new menu option.

Also you can use built-in spatial query processing tool: `Select by location`. You can find it in menu `Vector -> Research Tools -> Select by location` or also in processing toolbox.

Comment: My Processing tolls is enabled but I still do not see Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Count points in polygon

Comment: @Dragan Do you see other functions in Vector menu? If you can find `Count points in polygon` in processing toolbox, does it works?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which tools of `Count in Polygon` do you need. But they are located inside the Processing menu as you can see below. You can search for points, and you will have many tools:

[image]

Regarding `Spatial Query`, you may need to use `Plugin Manager` to download `Spatial Query` if it is not already downloaded. It should be located under `Vector -> Spatial Query`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related to Spatial Query that was the problem, I just enable it in my Plugins